# Swift 3 and Magical Record

Tags: ios, swift3, magicalrecord

I'm trying to use Magical Record with swift 3 and I can't seem to get the online tutorials to work.

I have this in the bridging header:

```
#define MR_SHORTHAND
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord.h>
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord+ShorthandMethods.h>
```

In my swift file, I've declared the following trying to get a fetch result

```
var inAppDetail: InAppDetail!
var inAppPackage: InAppPackage!
private var inAppPackageResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<InAppPackage>?
private var inAppDetailResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<InAppDetail>?
let packagePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "price > 0")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    if inAppDetailResultsController == nil{
        inAppDetailResultsController = InAppDetail.MR_fetchAllSortedBy("order", ascending: true, withPredicate: nil, groupBy: nil, delegate: self)

    }

    if inAppPackageResultsController == nil{
        inAppPackageResultsController = InAppPackage.MR_fetchAllSortedBy("order", ascending: true, withPredicate: packagePredicate, groupBy: nil, delegate: self)
    }

}
```

I'm getting a cannot convert value error if I leave the MR_ prefix and if I remove it. It's saying the types has no member 'fetchAllSortedBy'.

My magical record is working in my objective C files but not working in this swift file.

Did I miss declaring something somewhere?

Comment: What is the `cannot convert value error`? That is the real problem here.